# Separating info in a string from a file (Java)

Tags: java, string, file, split, int

I'm trying to read a file containing the name of a movie followed by a rating ranging from 1-10. Currently each line looks something like this:

"21 Jump Street" 8
"Harry Potter" 7
and so on

Is there a way to take the movie name and assign it to a string and then take the rating and add it to an integer? The file doesn't have to be formatted this way and can be changed if it makes it easier. Currently the code I have for reading each line is as follows:

```
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("E:\testing.txt")))
    {
        String sCurrentLine;
        String name;
        int rating;
        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            >>need code here<<
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I'm sorry if a similar question has been asked, I had a look but didn't find anything.

Comment: Look up "CSV", "JSON", or "XML" for example, there are numerous parsers for this kind of data representation around.

Comment: `>>need code here<<` - have you tried *anything*? Starting from the String.indexOf() or substring() for example?

Comment: *The file doesn't have to be formatted this way* how do you expect to *find something when you don't know where it is..*?

Comment: @TheLostMind I think the OP means that he has a list that he made in that format and he wants a way to read it from the program, but he can also change the format if necessary for the code.

Comment: @ Smutje I will have a look at those, thanks!
@ Eel Lee I was trying to use the split function but it didn't seem to be the right approach from what I tried, was looking for a point in the right basically.
@ TheLostMind It will be formatted consistently but if formatting it differently makes it easier then it's not hard to change the file ie no quotations around the name etc

Answer (score 0):

First decide on the exact format you want to use. If you're going for a simple txt file as now, you could use the split function on the sCurrentLine string to separate the values and then convert the second one to an int.